# How do we test the following series for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do we test the convergence of the following series: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac {(100.1\cos(100.1\log(k+1)) + (.45)\sin(100.1\log(k+1)))} {(k+1)^.55}$

I have a MATLAB script (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72141-series-convergence-calculator?s_tid=blogs_rc_4) that says the following:

*The series expression:
series_expr =
$((9*sin((1001*log(k + 1))/10))/20 + (1001*cos((1001*log(k + 1))/10))/10)/(k + 1)^(11/20)$
with starting k = 1,
converges to between:
445.61648642 and 445.65710003
by the Alternating Series Test*

But I want to be understand the process how we conclude that (I don't know MATLAB). Can someone please explain?

Comment: The claim about the alternating series test is definitely wrong, since this series doesn't satisfy the hypotheses of the alternating series test. I don't think the series does converge (the numerator oscillates too slowly for there to be consistent cancellation). I would divide the summation range over $k$ into ranges where $100.1\log(k+1)$ is between consecutive multiples of $\frac\pi2$ or something like that, then estimate the sum over each subrange; I believe the resulting expressions will not tend to $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the reply. Are there established libraries for testing similar summations for convergence (I couldn't find any in MATLAB). I somewhat understand what you are suggesting but is there no standard test that we can apply to such series (with trigonometric terms in the numerator as above)?

Comment: [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) is the closest thing I know to what you might be describing, but I don't believe this series meets its hypotheses.